# Redis cache optimization in .NET 8

Tags: .net, performance, caching, redis

The performance is not up to mark when serializing/deserializing a big JSON file (~3 MB). We are using Microsoft JSON serialization. Is there any other serialization that would help to optimize the cache and provide good serialization/deserialization performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution that met the requirements, so it took me 2-3 days to find the necessary solution. We use Protobuf-net for binary serialization/deserialization, and I've also created a small sample - https://github.com/mukesh82-net/RedisProtoBuf

Answer (score 0):

`System.Text.Json` is quite fast since it was originally designed with perfromance in mind. Here are some "official" benchmarks results [@github](https://github.com/dotnet/performance/pull/2740) (though a bit dated).

You can try switching to [using source generation in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation?pivots=dotnet-6-0) which can have some perfromance benefit but in general constantly serializing/deserializing relatively large JSON file back and forth does not sound like the best idea. It seems like you should consider using [in-memory caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with some pub/sub functionality to maintain local copies in sync (possibly on top of Redis).

Comment: There are a lot of files so the in-memory cache would be difficult.

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya Redis is in-memory) Do you need all of them all the time? Are all of them 3+ Mbs? Please share your deserialization code. How long does it take to deserialize a single file?